# pygmsh: how to create 3D mesh from 2D cross-sections

Tags: python, 3d, mesh, gmsh

I have two 2D cross sections defined as a list of points stored in `shapely.Polygon` and I want to create a 3D mesh by lofting the first cross-section (`cs1`) to the second cross-section (`cs2`). This is similar to extrude, but instead of a simply adding depth `d` to a 2D shape, I want to join two 2D shapes at a given depth `d`.

I could not find an inbuilt function in `pygmsh` to accomplish this. However, `pygmsh` offer a range of geometry primitives that I may be able to use to get what I want.

Note, that the polygons `cs1` and `cs2` could be arbitrary and may contain holes. I don't know how I would accomplish this, but right now I am trying to solve the simplest case where I am trying to create a 3D mesh from two square cross sections as shown below. The 3d shape is encapsulated by the two squares and the black bold lines.

[image: 3D visualization of cs1 and cs2]

I tried extruding my 2D shapes using `pygmsh.geo.Geometry().extrude` but that is not something I want to do here.

I am attempting to manually create the 3D volume using the following steps:

1. From the polygons, get `curve_loop`
2. Use `curve_loop` to create `surface`
3. create `surface loop` from the list of `surface` defining the shell and holes.
4. create `volume` from the `surface loop` of shell and holes

But I have stumbled at the 2nd step to create surface from curve loop:

```py
# Create the 2D polygons
poly1 = geom.add_polygon(polygon1.exterior.coords)
poly2 = geom.add_polygon(polygon2.exterior.coords)

# add curve loop to surface 
surf1 = geom.add_surface(poly1.curve_loop)
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Exception: Wrong definition of surface 3: 5 borders instead of 3 or 4
```

I do not know how to solve it.